# apt-get does not work after a failed install

Tags: 16.04, apt, dependencies

I installed 16.04 the other day.  Today I decided I'd rather use KDE than the default desktop, so I ran

```
sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop
```

This failed in the dependency `kde-config-telepathy-accounts`, apparently because the file `/usr/share/accounts/services/google-im.service` is also part of the package `account-plugin-google`.  Using the `-f` flag does not help.

The problem now is that `apg-get` will not install anything any more because of this broken dependency.  Nor will it remove or purge `kubuntu-desktop`.

How do I either fix the dependency problem, or otherwise fix `apt-get`?  Thanks.